# Intermediate redirection in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i'm working with a struts2 application.

I have a form that once his is submit trigger an action :

```
<action name="AddDataAction" class="saisie.AddAction" method="add">
```

I need to create an intermediate page where the user need to log again before doing this action.

The tough thing is that I can only modify struts.xml to create that intermediate state and that after the user log in, it must execute this addDataAction method with the parameters from the form (to be save in a database).

I thought about interceptor but could they redirect to a jsp and call an action to verify the user login while conserving the data of the form to be save if the user log correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use result type redirectAction to achieve this.

```
<action name="OtherAction" class="saisie.OtherAction" method="otherMethod">
    <result name="redirect" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">loginAction</param>
        <param name="yourParamName">${yourParamName}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

You can keep the parameter values by adding them to the result. Note the use of ${}. What this does is it calls the corresponding getters and adds them to the url. Then on the next page these values will be mapped to the corresponding variables using setters

You can read more about redirectAction results [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

Comment: So after the call of the redirectAction to an action that verify the login of the user, does the method add from AddAction is automatly called ? (like a recursive implementation)

Comment: No. You need to redirect to that too and add parameters

Comment: If i understand right, your code will execute the method add from AddAction before it redirect to the other action, so i should only put the type redirect and in my new action make an redirectAction in the result to an action that call the method add from AddAction.

Comment: Sorry you are right. You redirect to login from the other action and then from to add. I edited it